# How to convert to a web response from a record/data-frame

Tags: dataframe, record, python-3.6, httpwebresponse, aiohttp

I have an application where I am returning a data frame/record. I want to return a web response, how should I convert it to. Tried dumping in son but didn't work using `web.jsonresponse`.

Here is the return type that I want to convert into web.response so that I can use the `status` field of response.

`[<Record id='CORN' description='primary subject of interest'>]`

Comment: What package is creating the `Record`? Without that information it's hard to answe, but you can probably use something like `web.jsonresponse({'id': record.id, 'description': record.description})`. Or perhaps `Record` has a `.dict()` method?

Comment: Thanks @SColvin. Your answer gave me hints to look further. So I wanted to convert from record returned by `cursor` and `dataframe`. DataFrame has a to son method so used that with `web.jsonresponse`

Comment: You still haven't said what package is creating `Record` which is the key piece of information for this question.

Comment: Sorry @SColvin if the above comment wasn't clear. The record is generated from cursor object of `aiohttp` when trying to read rows of db table so like this: `async for record in stmt.cursor(*str_values)` that gets appended into list called result. Later, I am also converting this list of records into pandas data frame as `pd.DataFrame(result)`. I found method of data frame to convert to json using `to_json` and for records, I am doing similar to what you told me. Thank you.

Comment: No. Aiohttp has no database connection support and no such record type. sounds like you're very confused.